# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable always returns 2

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Google Play Services Library to my Android app. But there is an issue about isGooglePlayServicesAvailable function.

Although my play services is up to date, it returns 2 which means  SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED according to documentation.

My code is below:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int statusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(LoginSigninActivity.this);
    if( statusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        Log.e("statuscode",statusCode+"");
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(statusCode))
        {
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    statusCode,
                    LoginSigninActivity.this,
                    REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                errorDialog.show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_google_play_services_not_found),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Error dialog is always shown.

Comment: Can you show us also the logcat error? That says something like "required xxxxx but found yyyyyy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it should not.

Device with android 4.4.4 has play service version 5.0.89 where as devices with android L preview has play service version 5.2.08. This is reason why android studio ask you to update your play service version to 5.2.08. So, for now use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

If you are using android L emulator, i think you should use 5.2.08.

And if you want to update your play service to 5.2 see [this](https://plus.google.com/+DerekRoss/posts/G2LJ7vDRbc7).

Comment: My device is Android 4.4.2 and if I follow the error dialog I cannot update because it is already up to date. By the way I'm using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

Comment: Either update it to 5.2 using the link i gave you or use version 5.0.89.

Comment: There is no link, I'm afraid.

Comment: If I want to support Android 4 and above, would it be safe to use 5.0.89?

Comment: use version 4.something. because you can not get 5.+ in your Android 4.4.2. 5.+ is only available for android L. see my update bellow.

Comment: I have an 4.1.1 which has play services 5.0.89.

Comment: google did not give 5.0.89 in google play store.current version is 4.4.52. I think you manually update your play service for your device. @ Jitender

Comment: I don't remember updating it. Also, I have version 5.0.89 on my 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. I used latest  play services version: 5.+ to develop may app. But my device which has Kitkat uses play services version: 4.4.52. It always said `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` because i build an app which uses upper version of play service but device has lower version.

My suggestion is use lower play services version to develop your app or use device which uses upper version of play service.